# CruiseControl and JSONP API

Tags: json, cruisecontrol.net, jsonp, cruisecontrol

Im working on a project to connect to Hudson CI server and Hudson compatible CI servers. I was under the impression CruiseControl has a JSONP API the same as Hudson's but cannot find any documentation on any JSON/P API.

Does anyone here have a cruisecontrol server and can confirm this for me? also what is the URL like? ie: www.domain.com:port/api/json

Also could someone give me a capture of what the output of the json file is like? It would be a huge help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I do not know about cruisecontrol but I'll focus my answer on JSONP requests.

[What is JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp)

The easiest way to do JSONP request is to use that [alternative solution to jQuery's implementation of JSONP](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) which simplify JSONP requests calling.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, however my issue is not with JSONP. I already have working JSONP communication. My issue is I do not know the specific format of the cruisecontrol api and the url location to such api.